# different way for <jsp:useBean>

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

There is  -

```
<html>
<body>
         <jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And -

```
<html>
<body>
         <%
             Object user = session.getAttribute("user.UserData") ; 
         %>
</body>
</html>
```

Assume `user.UserData` exists on the `session` . is there any differnce between the two ways  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well known issue in JSPs is: avoid everything you can on using Java code with your page (.jsp). 
So the first approach fits better, do you agree? Taglibs `<jsp:useBean />` among others are a nice way of accessing code without mixing the layers. This concepts I barely introduced are part of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) "specification".

-- EDIT --

The second way of acessing a bean is known as scriptlets and should be avoided as always as possible. A brief comparison can be found here [JSTL vs jsp scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535423/jstl-vs-jsp-scriptlets).

Answer (score 3):

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>
```

is equivalent to

```
<%
    Object userDataObject = session.getAttribute("user") ; // id="user" of <jsp:useBean> maps to session attribute name "user"
%>
```

Besides, the scriptlet only reads existing data from session or returns null if no attribute is found.
If <jsp:useBean> finds attribute "user" in session to be null,
It will create an instance of 'user.UserData' and add to attribute "user" in session scope.

Comment: so what the "user.UserData" in jsp:useBean mean ?

Comment: the Object in session will be an instance of class "user.UserData". i.e. <jsp:useBean> will automatically type cast from class "Object" to "user.UserData. In terms of scriptlet - user.UserData userDataObject = (user.UserData) session.getAttribute("user") ;