# How to pass scriptlet value to text of combobox?

Tags: jsp, html-select

I want to pass the value of `name` to text as combobox. I am getting value of `name` from database.

```
{
 String name=resultset.getString(1);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Why you should use JSTL than JSP scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535423/jstl-vs-jsp-scriptlets). You should start use `JSTL`.

I've given you the scriptlet code here. You can iterate the resultset between `select tag` and set values for option.

```
<select name="username">
    <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <option value="<%=resultset.getString(1)%>"><%=resultset.getString(1)%></option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```